# CASE expression sum - issue when joining to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, case

I have a case expression in a stored procedure summing an account field, and then inserting into a user id. The logic works... until joining to another table.

I tried adding distinct counts, and additional tables to the query, but still when I join to another table it applies the 1 value when I want it to be 0 to the account.

This is the calculation in the stored proc;

```
INSERT INTO #SUMMARY_TEMP (USER_ID,FSN_CNT )
(SELECT USER_ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN A_GROUP_CD = 'RED' AND A_TYPE_CD = 'FSN' THEN REC_COUNT ELSE 0 END)
) AS 'FSN_CNT',
FROM (SELECT A_ACCOUNT_NBR,
             A_USER_ID,
             A_GROUP_CD,
             A_TYPE_CD,
             COUNT(*) AS REC_COUNT
      FROM EXCEPTION_DETAIL
           INNER JOIN #STAFF ON A_REPORT_DT = @REPORT_DT 
                            AND (A_USER = B_USER_ID)
      GROUP BY A_ACCOUNT_NBR,
               A_USER_ID_ID,
               A_GROUP_CD,
               A_TYPE_CD) EXCEPTIONS
GROUP BY A_USER_ID,
A_ACCOUNT_NBR)
```

This is the result which is what I expect for 2 USER Ids

```
A_ACCOUNT_NBR   USER_ID     FSN_CNT 
123456          HENRY       0   
123498          HENRY       1   
374933          JOE         1   
474930          JOE         0
```

but when I join to another table the data looks like

```
A_ACCOUNT_NBR   USER_ID     FSN_CNT 
123456          HENRY       1   
123498          HENRY       1   
374933          JOE         1   
474930          JOE         1
```

Its applying the 1 value to account 123456 & 474930 when it should be 0.
I think its because the other table does not have the `ACCOUNT_NBR` column - I am joining on `USER_ID` and so it applies the 1 to all `ACCOUNT_NBR` from table A.

Thanks for all the suggestions, I tried using a CTE, and the counts now look good, but its created duplicate rows as shown below. Any suggestions on how to remove the duplication, below is the join I am using for the CTE;

```
select cte.*, jt.USER_ID
from cte
join EXCEPTION_DETAIL jt on cte.USER_ID=jt.USER_ID                                                  

USER    ACCOUNT_NBR FSN_CNT
HENRY   123456      0
HENRY   123456      0
HENRY   123498      1
HENRY   123498      1

JOE     374933      1
JOE     374933      1
JOE     474930      0
JOE     474930      0
```

Comment: Whitespace is really important to creating reading SQL. Do try to avoid writing SQL that is all ragged left aligned.

Comment: Now that I've aligned that SQL, and it's readable, you can see that it isn't valid. Are you asking how fix the syntax error in your SQL? You've not provided us with any sample data here, only the results you received and what you're after. We need to know what your data looks like before hand, not after. We can't help you get from A to B, when you give us details of B and C.

Comment: sorry for the alignment issue :) the sql does run, theres a typo in there after 'FSN_CNT', - that comma shouldn't be there, my bad.

Comment: That isn't the only problem, @Blowers. The statement after the `INSERT` doesn't start with a `SELECT`, it starts with a subquery, that returns multiple columns (one without a name) and it also has a trailing `)` at the end.

Comment: Based on your problem, the case statement provides the only clear hint: `CASE WHEN A_GROUP_CD = 'RED' AND A_TYPE_CD = 'FSN' THEN REC_COUNT ELSE 0 END`.  You need to look at the data after it is joined and confirm the values of `A_GROUP_CD` and `A_TYPE_CD`.  The case statement returns the value of `REC_COUNT` if both conditions are true, else it returns your desired 0.  It's also possible `REC_COUNT` equals 0.

Comment: Your query returns two columns, but your sample data has three.  Something is off.

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the 1st query by using cte and join with it next level like below

```
with cte as
(
(SELECT USER_ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN A_GROUP_CD = 'RED' AND A_TYPE_CD = 'FSN' THEN REC_COUNT ELSE 0 END)
) AS 'FSN_CNT',
FROM (SELECT A_ACCOUNT_NBR,
             A_USER_ID,
             A_GROUP_CD,
             A_TYPE_CD,
             COUNT(*) AS REC_COUNT
      FROM EXCEPTION_DETAIL
           INNER JOIN #STAFF ON A_REPORT_DT = @REPORT_DT 
                            AND (A_USER = B_USER_ID)
      GROUP BY A_ACCOUNT_NBR,
               A_USER_ID_ID,
               A_GROUP_CD,
               A_TYPE_CD) EXCEPTIONS
GROUP BY A_USER_ID,
A_ACCOUNT_NBR)
) select cte.*,jt.USER_ID from cte join jointable_name jt on cte.USER_ID=jt.USER_ID
```